# Scenekit gesture recognizer and overlaySKScene touches

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Currently working on a game with scene kit in swift. I've got a joystick added to a `SKScene`, which is then attached to my scene kit game scene. Typical HUD overlay for controls.

```
    let hudScene = SKScene(size: view.frame.size)
    scnView.overlaySKScene = hudScene
```

I have also added a joystick to `hudScene` and want to add some buttons. Now, all of this works fine until I add a gesture recognizer to my main game scene. Once I do, all tap interaction with the `hudScene` is completely ignored. Even if I tap on the joystick and log what node was tapped at that location, it gives me the node in my game scene and completely ignores the nodes in `hudScene`.

**Can anybody provide any insight into why this is happening?**

For reference, the touch events for the joystick are implemented from [this library](https://github.com/MitrophD/Swift-SpriteKit-Analog-Stick/blob/master/AnalogStick%20Demo/AnalogStick%20Demo/AnalogJoystick.swift), and my gesture recognizer is implimented like this:

```
    let touchDownRec = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTouchDown(_:)) )
    touchDownRec.minimumPressDuration = 0
    touchDownRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(touchDownRec)
```

Comment: After playing around some more, If i implement another set of `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` etc in my game scene, both the joystick and scene touches are reconized. So it looks like when I am implimenting a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` it overrides the joystick's `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... you have to replace the **touchesBegan** with a **TapGesture**, or replace the **UILongPressGestureRecognizer** with **touchesEnded**, but is more precise the first option.